# How to multiply two textbox values and display answer to third in c#?

Tags: c#, events, textbox

In my program have 3 textboxes. which are for subtotal,discount and grand total.Subtotal value will display after some calculations and I should type discount manually.Then after type discount value in textbox i need to display grandtotal value automatically in grandtotal textbox.How to do this.I try this

```
txtgrandtotal.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtdiscount.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtsubtotal.Text)).ToString();
```

But it didn't work for textchange event

Comment: textChanged on which control?

Comment: look into tryparse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the TextChange Event on the TextBox `txtdiscount` control.

Once you added the event you can do your calculation like this:

```
private void txtdiscount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtgrandtotal.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtdiscount.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtsubtotal.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: After insert data into database I need to clear grandtotal textbox value. Whith this event I cant use txtgrandtotal.text=""; why? How can I clear this textbox?

Comment: @Adam do you have a button or some control, where you insert the data into the database?